# Defining a function to print grades against certain values in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm pretty new to Python. I'm learning new stuff every day, so my code might be rudimentary. But any help is appreciated.

I'm trying to define a function which would read the file and use one column of the data and associate some text against it.

In this sample problem, I have a file which some marks in a column named `Final` and I want to create a new data frame column which has grades against those final marks based on a marking scheme.

Here's my code:

```
def reportGrade(filename):
    data=pd.read_csv(filename, sep=',')
    k=[]
    for scores in data.Final:
        if 91<=scores<=100:
            k=k.append['A']
        elif 85<=scores<91:
            k=k.append['B']
        elif 70<=scores<85:
            k=k.append['C']
        elif 0<=scores<70:
            k=k.append['D']
    for i in k:
        data['grades']=k[i]
    return (data.grades())
reportGrade("class_grades_demo.csv")
```

Is this the correct way to do it. I'm getting an error for this code. But the logic for this code sounded fine to me. Also is there a better way or any other better approach to this problem. I though i could use some `lamda` function but it didn't work and neither did `bisect`. Please help. Tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `cut`:

```
df['grade'] = pd.cut(df['Final'],
                     bins = [0, 70,85,91,101],
                     right=False,
                     labels=['D','C','B','A']
                    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 


df = pd.DataFrame({"final": [95,85,45,77,99,41]})

cond1 = (100 >= df["final"]) & (df["final"]>= 91)
cond2 = (90 >= df["final"]) & (df["final"]>= 81)
cond3 = (80 >= df["final"]) & (df["final"]>= 71)

df["grades"] = np.select([cond1, cond2, cond3], ["A", "B", "C"], "D")

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  final grades
0   95  A
1   85  B
2   45  D
3   77  C
4   99  A
5   41  D
```

**If you want function to do the same**

```
def grade_func(data, col, new_col):
    cond1 = (100 >= data[col]) & (data[col]>= 91)
    cond2 = (90 >= data[col]) & (data[col]>= 81)
    cond3 = (80 >= data[col]) & (data[col]>= 71)

    data[new_col] = np.select([cond1, cond2, cond3], ["A", "B", "C"], "D") 

    return data

df = pd.DataFrame({"final": [95,85,45,77,99,41]})

grade_func(df, "final", "grades")
```

*Note: You can add/remove function parameters based on your requirement*